# Spring Test HTMLUnit NoSuchMethod CookieManager.getCookies(URL)

Tags: java, spring, maven, htmlunit, spring-web

I'm having an problem running HTMLUnit tests using spring-test-htmlunit. When calling getPage() on an instance of WebClient, I get a noSuchMethod error as follows:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager.getCookies(Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.htmlunit.HtmlUnitRequestBuilder.cookies(HtmlUnitRequestBuilder.java:267)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.htmlunit.HtmlUnitRequestBuilder.buildRequest(HtmlUnitRequestBuilder.java:104)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.htmlunit.MockMvcWebConnection.getResponse(MockMvcWebConnection.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.htmlunit.MockMvcWebConnection.getResponse(MockMvcWebConnection.java:96)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.htmlunit.DelegatingWebConnection.getResponse(DelegatingWebConnection.java:68)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1357)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1274)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:382)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:304)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:451)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:436)
```

I've tried excluding the HTMLUnit version from spring-test-htmlunit and adding the latest version. I also have a dependency for nekoHTML that is needed for thymeleaf template compilation.

**relevant pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.21</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.test.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test-htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**the offending call**

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080/");
```

Comment: There is a conflict of dependencies here, most likely caused by transitive dependencies being introduced. I find the dependency plugin in maven to be quite useful for these cases, i.e. "mvn dependency:tree". It will give you a tree display of dependencies, this will be of help to you so you can add explicit excludes on versions you don't want on your classpath. Also take a look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this is a dependency conflict, you can print down the currently used JARs by something like:

```
System.out.println(WebClient.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
System.out.println(HTMLElements.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

And ensure the Neko version is compatible with the corresponding HtmlUnit version.

Also, spring boot includes specific HtmlUnit version, which may not be what you want.